# Python. Is there a way to pick a random def?

Tags: python, function, random

I want to store each Callout in a def function
for example:

```
def shooting():
    print("bang bang")

def mugging():
    print("money, now!")
callout = ['shooting', 'mugging']
randomthing = random.choice(callout)
print(randomthing + "()")
```

So each callout is stored in the def function. Then it is randomized in callout and randomthing. Then (I know this part is wrong) I want it to call either mugging() or shooing() but with a 50/50 chance.

Comment: @jhpratt You don't need "lambdas". `lambda` just defines a function, the same as `def`; you can have an array of functions no matter how they're defined.

Comment: Just change your code to `callout = [shooting, mugging]`, storing the actual functions rather than their names. Then, you can just do `randomthing()` to call whichever function you picked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it! Just remove the quotes, and store the function name directly. Functions in Python are just like variables:

```
callout = [shooting, mugging]
randomthing = random.choice(callout)
print(randomthing())
```

Comment: This seems to have worked the best! But now it seems to be adding the word None under the bang bang.

Example:

    bang bang
    None

Comment: @T.ps That's because each of your functions does a `print`, and then doesn't return anything. If you don't return anything, the default value is `None`. So when you `print(randomthing())`, it's going to print that `None`. What you probably want to do is change your functions to _return_ a string, instead of _printing_ it.

Comment: How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: You could change your functions to `return 'bang bang'` and `return 'money, now!'` Alternatively, you could call `randomthing()`, rather than `print(randomthing())`